# Fast pixel drawing on the screen

Tags: c++, winapi, pixel

I need to fill a window with pixels, very fast of course.
This is for an 'old school' project with software 3D graphics (proof of concept).

The requirements are:

- Pointer to the screen buffer to write colors and a method to display it
- No OpenGL, Direct3D or SDL
- Pure WinAPI

**Question: How do I draw pixels on a window with WinAPI?**

Comment: And what is the question? You don't have a question mark?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not clear. I edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `CreateDIBSection` to create a `HBITMAP` bitmap with handle along with raw pointer to bits
- `BitBlt` to copy data between `HDC` device contexts, from a device context with the bitmap (see above) selected into, to the other one associated with the window you are to "paint on"

Comment: I'm not quite deep in WinAPI. Could you point me to an example on how to do this?